# Lambda function return a function with different memory location?

Tags: javascript, lambda, functional-programming, closures

So here is some code i am trying to work with

```
const someFunc = (a) => (b) => a + b;
const someArray = [1, 2];
const firstOrder = someArray.map(a => someFunc(a));

firstOrder[0] === firstOrder[1]; // returns false
```

I am not sure why this is a function with a different memory location.

I was expecting to accomplish a similar functionality wherein

```
firstOrder[0] === firstOrder[1]; // should return true
```

I am not sure if something like this is even possible.

The primary motivation here is to avoid memory footprint.

I guess i could use some help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Functions with different scopes are never `===` to each other. Still, sounds a bit like premature optimization, unless you're run a performance test and have determined that this is indeed a bottleneck..? If I had to, I'd save a reference to `someArray`, and use that and a `someFunc` that returns a number instead of a function, instead of using `.map`, that way you just have *one* array of primitives and *one* function in memory,

Comment: `someFunc(1)` and `someFunc(2)` are very different functions, aren't they? They won't even return the same result when called with the same input: `someFunc(1)(3)` != `someFunc(2)(3)`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance not sure if i get it, it would be really helpful if you could write some code it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, functions with different scopes are never `===` to each other.

The memory overhead of a simple function is next to nothing, especially on modern hardware and modern JS engines, so before spending effort on this, make sure this is not a case of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization) - run a performance test, and make sure this is actually a bottleneck first.

You're currently passing around an array of functions, presumably so they can be iterated through and called by something later. Consider passing around *just* the `someArray` and a `someFunc` that takes 2 arguments and returns a number instead; an array of primitives takes less memory than an array of functions. For example, the following code takes up ~1,400M memory on Chrome for me:

```
const someFunc = (a) => (b) => a + b;
const arrayOfFunctions = Array.from({ length: 1e7 }, (_, i) => someFunc(i));
// eventually use arrayOfFunctions
```

But if you just store your `someArray`, and call the function only when you need access to the final *number* it returns, the memory footprint is much lighter:

```
const someFunc = (a, b) => a + b;
const someArray = Array.from({ length: 1e7 }, (_, i) => i);
// eventually, once you need access to the final numbers, iterate through someArray and call someFunc with it:
// ...
const theBArgument = 5;
const result = someArray.map(a => someFunc(a, theBArgument));
```

Before the `result`, this uses only ~120M memory on Chrome, for me.